# Checking the position of my jobs within a queue in LSF

Tags: job-scheduling, lsf

Is there a way to check the position of my jobs within an [LSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF) queue?

If I run:

`bjobs -u all -q my_queue`

I get a list of jobs from all users within `my_queue`, but is this list sorted by the position of my jobs within the queue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you're interested in pending jobs.

This will show all pending jobs in a queue.

`bjobs -u all -p -q my_queue`

This list is sorted by position in queue.

The position is based on job priority and submit time.

Keep in mind, what is displayed is not a perfect indication of when a job will run. LSF will start jobs as the correct resources are available. A job requiring a lot of resources may be first in the queue. But if the required resources are not available, LSF will start other jobs behind it that are within the available resources.

Comment: Also, the scheduling algorithm (e.g., user-level fair share), and user/group limits will affect things.

Answer (score 1):

To check progress on individual job -

```
bpeek -f <job_id>
```

This command sort of creates an output stream where the job redirects it's output.

Answer (score 0):

`squeue -l [queue name]`

lists the priorities for all users.
Jobs of users with higher priorities are run first.